# Python - Amateurish code

Tags: python, getopts

First of all, my code does work as expected at least to some extend.
The intention of the program is to extract data from a DBMS in order to create a CSV-dump and transfer it to a FTP-server. That does work. My to issues:

- The functions of the class seem to be bloated with
  "self."-references. How can that be optimized or is that the way it
  ought to be? It looks overloaded to me.
- The population of the plist has been done very ineptly. The main
  function does not exit the program if the number of arguments does
  not equal 2. How can this be archived respectively be done better?

Here the code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import re
import os
import csv
import sys
import getopt
import ftplib
import ntpath

#os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = "en_US.ISO8859-1"
#os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = ".UTF8"

def main(argv):
    inputfile = ''
    outputfile = ''
    usage = 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
    flist = []
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print usage
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            inputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            outputfile = arg
        elif len(sys.argv) != 2:
            print usage
            sys.exit(2)
    flist.append(inputfile)
    flist.append(outputfile)
    return flist

class Extractor(object):

    def __init__(self, iput, oput):
        self.oracle_server = "my_oracle_server"
        self.oracle_password = "my_oracle_password"
        self.oracle_port = "1521"
        self.oracle_sid = "MYSID"
        self.oracle_user = "MYUSER"
        self.ftp_server = 'my_ftp_psw'
        self.ftp_user = 'my_ftp_user'
        self.ftp_passwort = 'my_ftp_passwort'
        self.sql_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),iput) 
        self.csv_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),oput)
        self.dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn(self.oracle_server, self.oracle_port, self.oracle_sid)
        self.connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user=self.oracle_user, password=self.oracle_password, dsn=self.dsnStr)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def execute_sql(self, file):
        self.f = open(file)
        self.sql_statement = self.f.read()
        self.cursor.execute(self.sql_statement)

    def extract_from_db(self):
        self.column_list = [i[0] for i in self.cursor.description]
        self.columns = ';'.join(self.column_list)
        with open(self.csv_file,'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(self.columns+"\n")
            writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter =";")
            for row in self.cursor:
                writer.writerow(row)

    def transfer_file(self):
        print "Transferring " + self.csv_file + " ..."
        self.session = ftplib.FTP(self.ftp_server, self.ftp_user, self.ftp_passwort )
        self.file = open(self.csv_file,'rb')
        self.session.storlines('STOR ' + ntpath.basename(self.csv_file), self.file)     # send the file
        self.file.close()
        self.session.quit()
        print "Complete."


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plist=main(sys.argv[1:]) # very inept, doesn't not exit as intended when number of arguments does not equal 2
    ext = Extractor(plist[0], plist[1])
    ext.execute_sql(ext.sql_file)
    ext.extract_from_db()
    ext.cursor.close()
    ext.connection.close()
    ext.transfer_file()
```

Comment: Hi there! For working code that you want constructive feedback on, you can post on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). This is probably too broad and vague for Stack Overflow, but would be right at home on CR.

Comment: [*"Users who are unfamiliar with the C `getopt()` function or who would like to write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the `argparse` module instead."*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html) Then once you've fixed that, take the rest of the question to [codereview.se]

Comment: Ok, will do so. Thanks.